# создание отчета Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Не могу никак разобраться с созданием отчета в PowerBi
Дано: БД, где есть 3 таблицы. 1 хранит в себе ссылка на связующую, айдишники и даты, вторая - связующая между 1 и 3, 3 - хранит в себе имена и айдишники.

Необходимо вывести в отчет каунт по датам, сохранив возможность фильтрации по промежутку даты и доп отчеты, где такой же отчет, но для своего "имени/идшника" в 3 таблице.

Comment: Сейчас есть 2 варианта. 1 - отдельный запрос с каунтами + параметр в запросах. Не удается настроить его фильтр через отчет
2 - на основе таблицы каунты и тд, но использование среза не подошло, т.к. полей дат не 1. 
СУБД - Postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое оказалось невозможно на текущий момент. Параметры М для запросов работают только с Kusto